# Corner radius image Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiimageview

I'm trying to make this corner radius image...it's not exactly the same shape of the image..any easy answer instead of trying random numbers of width and height ?
thanks alot

[image]

```
 let rectShape = CAShapeLayer()
 rectShape.bounds = self.mainImg.frame
 rectShape.position = self.mainImg.center
 rectShape.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.mainImg.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.bottomLeft , .bottomRight ], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 50, height: 4)).cgPath
```

Comment: Go to wolframalpha.com and type in `center of circle through points (3, 0), (0, 3), and (0,-3)` and it will tell you the radius and center of your circle.  Substitute your own points of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use QuadCurve to get the design you want.

Here is a Swift `@IBDesignable` class that lets you specify the image and the "height" of the rounding in Storyboard / Interface Builder:

```
@IBDesignable

class RoundedBottomImageView: UIView {

    var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    @IBInspectable var image: UIImage? {
        didSet { self.imageView.image = image }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var roundingValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        doMyInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        doMyInit()
    }
    
    func doMyInit() {
        
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
        addSubview(imageView)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        imageView.frame = self.bounds

        let rect = self.bounds
        let y:CGFloat = rect.size.height - roundingValue
        let curveTo:CGFloat = rect.size.height + roundingValue
        
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        myBezier.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: y))
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: y), controlPoint: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: curveTo))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: 0))
        myBezier.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
        myBezier.close()
        
        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = myBezier.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskForPath
    
    }

}
```

Result with `300 x 200` image view, rounding set to `40`:

[image]

---

**Edit** - *(3.5 years later)...*

To answer @MiteshDobareeya comment, we can switch the rounded edge from Bottom to Top by transforming the bezier path:

```
let c = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: bounds.size.height))
        myBezier.apply(c)
```

It's been quite a while since this answer was originally posted, so a few changes:

- subclass `UIImageView` directly - no need to make it a `UIView` with an embedded `UIImageView`
- add a Bool `roundTop` var

  - if set to False (the default), we round the Bottom
  - if set to True, we round the Top
- re-order and "name" our path points for clarity

So, the basic principle:

[image]

We create a `UIBezierPath` and:

- move to `pt1`
- add a line to `pt2`
- add a line to `pt3`
- add a quad-curve to `pt4` with `controlPoint`
- close the path
- use that path for a `CAShapeLayer` mask

the result:

[image]

If we want to round the Top, after closing the path we can apply apply a `scale` transform using `-1` as the `y` value to **vertically mirror** it. Because that transform mirror it at "y-zero" we also apply a `translate` transform to move it back down into place.

That gives us:

[image]

Here's the updated class:

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedTopBottomImageView: UIImageView {
    
    @IBInspectable var roundingValue: CGFloat = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var roundTop: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let r = bounds
        
        let myBezier = UIBezierPath()
        
        let pt1: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.minY)
        let pt2: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.minY)
        let pt3: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.maxX, y: r.maxY - roundingValue)
        let pt4: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.minX, y: r.maxY - roundingValue)
        
        let controlPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: r.midX, y: r.maxY + roundingValue)
        
        myBezier.move(to: pt1)
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt2)
        myBezier.addLine(to: pt3)
        myBezier.addQuadCurve(to: pt4, controlPoint: controlPoint)
        myBezier.close()
        
        if roundTop {
            // if we want to round the Top instead of the bottom,
            //  flip the path vertically
            let c = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1) //.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: bounds.size.height))
            myBezier.apply(c)
        }
        
        let maskForPath = CAShapeLayer()
        maskForPath.path = myBezier.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskForPath
    }
    
}
```

Comment: please I draged an image view to storyboard and made its class  'RoundedBottomImageView' but it gives me in the simulator an red image according to the red background written in the code...can you explain the code please?

Comment: It's a `UIView` subclass, not `UIImageView`.

Comment: @DonMag Can you please let me know the same for the top side?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya - this would really be a good learning exercise for you, rather than just asking for the change. See the **Edit** to my answer, which should make it much easier for you to understand what's going on. I encourage you to read the description and examine the point illustration, and try to make the changes yourself... then examine my updated class.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks for adding a detailed description. Instead of using scale transformation, I did it with changes of the Y-axis values in addLine.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya - certainly a valid approach! Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  `UIView` extension. as

```
extension UIView {
    func setBottomCurve(){
        let offset = CGFloat(self.frame.size.height + self.frame.size.height/1.8)
        let bounds = self.bounds
        let rectBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x,
                                y: bounds.origin.y ,
                                width:  bounds.size.width,
                                height: bounds.size.height / 2)
        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(rect: rectBounds)


        let ovalBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x - offset / 2,
                                y: bounds.origin.y ,
                                width: bounds.size.width + offset,
                                height: bounds.size.height)

        let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: ovalBounds)
        rectPath.append(ovalPath)

        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = bounds
        maskLayer.path = rectPath.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
}
```

& use it in `viewWillAppear` like methods where you can get actual frame of UIImageView.

**Usage:**

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    //use it in viewWillAppear like methods where you can get actual frame of UIImageView
      myImageView.setBottomCurve()
 }
```