# How to Achieve bottom custom Curve and top Corner Radius in UIImageView?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uibezierpath, cornerradius

I am working on Profile Design. I want to achieve custom curve on bottom side of image and apply corner radios to Top side. I have tried it with RoundCorners method of UIBeziarPath. but i didn't got proper result.

Here is my try :-

1) I am using this method to achieve my result.

```
//MARK : - Extension set UIImageView Corner Radius
extension UIImageView {

    func roundCorners(_ corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = mask

    }
}
```

2) In viewDidLoad Method.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.imgView.roundCorners([.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 36)
        self.imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

3) Here is my Result :-

[image]

But, I want to achieve this result. Like, bottom Curve

[image]

Comment: Better if you try bezier curve

Comment: Use `UIBezierPath` with `.addQuadCurve` ... Here is a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445367/6257435

Answer (score 0):

You can add mask with any shape to imageView

Example:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
UIImageView* yourView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 200, 200)];
yourView.center = self.view.center;
yourView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg"];

yourView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview: yourView];

CGFloat roundedHeight = yourView.frame.size.height * 0.2;

CGFloat bottomOvalHeight = roundedHeight * 2;

//First part of mask - oval in the bottom
UIBezierPath *ovalPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                           yourView.frame.size.height - bottomOvalHeight, yourView.frame.size.width,
                                                                           bottomOvalHeight)];

//Second part of mask - rectangle from top to the middle of the oval
UIBezierPath *rectPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0,
                                                                     0,
                                                                     yourView.frame.size.width,
                                                                     yourView.frame.size.height - roundedHeight)];
//Make one mask from two parts
[rectPath appendPath:ovalPath];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.path = rectPath.CGPath;
yourView.layer.mask  = maskLayer;
}
```

Result:

[image]